# Responsively vertically align multiple lines of text in floated division

Tags: html, css

I have two divisions that need to be floated next to each other. The right one had an image and the left one has a small amount of text. What I want is for the text to be vertically aligned in the left division. If I set a line height I can get it to work but this causes problems on a resolution that requires to text to wrap.

I can't seem to work out how to sort it.

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div style="float: left;  width: 78%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 150px;">Text</div>
  <div style="float: right; width: 22%; display: inline-block;">
    <img alt="" src="path" style="width: 120px; height: 148px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean vertically aligned with respect to the entire viewport? Or to what exactly?

Comment: I need to vertically aligned in the division it's in so it will appear half way up the image.

Answer (score 3):

I would use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`:

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.td {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="td">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ut libero et odio rhoncus luctus a a nunc. Etiam et dolor magna. Vivamus semper mi in porta pellentesque.
  </div>
  <div class="td">
    <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/120x148" style="width: 120px; height: 148px;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This will work no matter the length of the text.

Comment: or simply use a table instead of divs

Comment: could you please explain in more details? what is that table will screw up? just wondering

Comment: You would have to override all of the browsers default table styles and making tables responsive is not a trivial task. Using `display` like this means you can easily switch between `table`, `block` etc with your media queries

Comment: TABLE with relative width (%) will behave as those divs from the question. I understand, that it is not simple to place TDs verticaly, but, looks like, in it not requirement in this particular case. In general yes, I agree with you, TABLE is not best practice, but in some case they work.

Comment: It may work but it's certainly not the correct element to use if you aren't displaying tabular data.

Comment: Is there any way of doing it without using the display table and table cell? I'd really like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @RichardYoung - There's a bunch of about half a dozen vertical alignment techniques that are widely covered on SO. You need to explain *why* display:table isn't what you want.